# Why are the if statements in my code not working?

Tags: c

The `if` statement to test the first two numbers in the array is not working and the `else` is not working.

I am creating a little game where you are able to roll a die three times, if the user rolls the die three times and gets the same number he is awarded 1500 points. If the user rolls the die and get 2 of the same numbers he is awarded 1200 points and if he rolls the die and get straight numbers(eg. 1, 2, 3 or 3, 4, 5, 6) he is awarded 1300 points else 600 points is deducted.

The `if` statement that is supposed to test if the first two numbers are the same is not working and the `else` is not working. I do not know how to get around this.

```
 void Roll(){
     int die[3] = {1, 1, 0}, i;
     /*for(i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        die[i] = 1 + rand() % 6;
     }*/
     printf("You rolled: \n");
     for(i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        printf("%d ", die[i]);
    printf("\n");

     checkPoints(die);
 }
 void checkPoints(int die[]){
     if(die[0] == die[1]){
        if(die[1] == die[2])
            pts += 1500;
     }
     else if((die[0] + 1) == die[1]){
        if((die[1] + 1) == die[2])
            pts += 1300;
     else if(die[0] == die[1]){
        pts += 1200;
     }
    else if(die[0] == die[2]){
        pts += 1200;
     }
    else if(die[1] == die[2]){
        pts += 1200;
     }
     else{
        pts -= 600;
     }

    showPoints();
 }
 void showPoints(){
     printf("Total points: %d\n", pts);
 }
```

Comment: `checkPoints` is not properly closed, there is a missing `}` bracket. Are you sure your program is compiling properly?

Comment: the problem are the ifs, i think the author assumes that the nested ifs are all taken into account for the else clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: Your nested `ifs` are not taken all into account for the `else` clause. You need to properly use `and (&&)` and `or (||)`

I think you have a little misunderstanding of how `if` and `else` work. Your problem lies in the fact that you do not use `and` and `or`.

This statement:

```
 if(die[0] == die[1]){
    if(die[1] == die[2])
        pts += 1500;
 }
 else if((die[0] + 1) == die[1]){
    // do smth
 }
```

Will not go in the else, if the first if statement is true, it will also not go into the `else`, no matter what the second `if` clause does.

What you want is:

```
if(die[0] == die[1] && die[1] == die[2]) {
    pts += 1500;
else if ...
```

The difference here is that all conditions of the first if must apply, if only one of the conditions fail, the else will be executed. Your own code will only go into the else if the first condition fails, the second one is not taken into account anymore, as it's another `if` construct in the new scope of the first `if`. The `else` is always only in relation to the `if` which it corresponds to, not to the following `if` in the scope of the first `if`.

Comment: That`s very helpful, but I want to find a way to do it without logical operators.

Comment: Why would you do that? The only way that would be achieveable is using over and over the same if statements and create an if path for every possibility... This wont give you any advantage, only cluttered and unreadable code. Also you shoujld state such limitations in the question.